# Cannot implicitly convert type 'integer' to 'NSString' -

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask very simple thing about conversion between type.

```
int theinteger = 75;

NSLog(@"Before theinteger is: %@", theinteger);

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theinteger];

NSLog(@"After theinteger is: %@", string);
```

Output is like

```
Before theinteger: 75
After theinteger: 114503696
```

What does this mean?  Why after conversion my data is changed to 114503696?

When I tried

```
int theinteger = -1;
```

It's OK

```
Before theinteger: -1
After theinteger: -1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any evidence of it, I assume `theinteger` is, in fact, of type `NSInteger` or `int`.

When using a specifier, try using *%i*:

```
NSInteger theinteger = 75;
NSLog(@"theinteger is: %i", theinteger);
```

**Output**

```
theinteger is: 75
```

[Here's a list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) of specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using %@ as a format specifier for an integer, as in your first log statement. However, my guess is the code you've posted here isn't actually the code you're using, because this line `NSLog(@"Before theinteger is: %@", the integer);` won't actually compile due to the space in "the integer". Can you copy/paste your actual code?

Anyway, `%@` is the format specifier for Objective-C objects. When `NSLog()` sees a `%@`, it substitutes it with the NSString returned by calling `-(NSString *)description` on the corresponding object in the variables list. In your case, `NSLog()` sees the %@ and assumes that means that theinteger is an Objective-C object, which it is not.

If you want to print an integer, you should use a format specifier of %i (or another of the several integer format specifiers):

`NSLog(@"Before theinteger is: %i", theinteger);`

Comment: int theinteger = 75;

NSLog(@"After theinteger is: %@", string);`code`